# is there is a (void)x; equivalent in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

I have a simple python code that does some thing like this

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/var/log"):
  #Some thing with root
  #Uses files
  #Doesn't use dirs
```

the variable `dir` is not used in this code section, however `pylint` is not exactly happy about it and complaining about `unused variable`

is there an `C` equivalent way ( `(void) dir ;` ) I can use to suppress this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, you can use an underscore `_` to represent a "throwaway" variable you arent going to use.

Example:

```
>>> _, b = (1, 2)
>>> b
2
```

So in your case:

```
for root, _, files in os.walk("/var/log"):
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: And this is not a real blackhole wildcard but rather a mere convention.